# When building for windows phone using VS.net cordova throws OsvCommonersion error

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I have tried vs.net 2013 and 2015

when building a cordova app for windows phone I get the following error.

**Severity  Description Project File    Line
Error   'System.Environment' does not contain a definition for 'OsvCommonersion' [F:\SDKMobile\MobileConsole2\bld\Debug\platforms\wp8\MobileConsole.csproj] MobileConsole2  Device.cs   72**

I can't find any docs on this

Gary

Answer (score 0):

I moved the node_modules out of the project directory and no longer get this error